# Legacy Core and Kernel Errors (Importing VS 2010 Pro Project into VS2017 Pro)

Tags: vb.net, version-control

I ran Dependency Walker on an assembly (.exe) after compiling in Debug (Any CPU) and it seems like there are older core and kernel issues.  The entire code is VB.NET 2010, so I am wondering why VS2017 Pro didn't clean those out?

Something interesting was that the Conversion to a new VS version did not occur, for which errors are shown -- it just showed the forms, modules, etc. as if there were no errors.

Should I try a Reload or something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The errors were caused by having old references or assembly libraries which called DLLs (like VBIDE.dll and MSCORE.DLL) in the applications folder.  There were very old references, some of which were to VB6.

Recall, remember that Visual Studio has always been dropping certain Windows forms controls over VB 2005, VB 2008, VB2010, etc. so you need to make sure those older controls are not in forms when you upgrade to e.g. VS 2017.